Using a lambda inside foreach()
I can use the foreach() function with a string, like so:
:call foreach([37,73], 'echo v:val')
37
73

or with a Funcref:
function Foobar(key,val)
  echo a:val
endfunction
:call foreach([37,73], function('Foobar'))
37
73

but it doesn't work with a lambda expression:
:call foreach([37,73], {key,val -> echo val})
E451: Expected }: val})
E116: Invalid arguments for function foreach

Many other functions (map(), filter(), reduce(), etc.) support lambda expressions. Was foreach() overlooked when lambda support was added, is this behavior a bug, or is my syntax not correct? I tested this in Vim 9.1 with patches 1-740 and Neovim v0.10.0 on Windows 10.

The issue here is not that foreach() doesn't accept a lambda, but that :echo is a command and is not valid inside a lambda expression.
The main issue is that foreach() doesn't return the evaluated values of the lambda expression, it only calls it for side effects, and expressions typically don't have side effects.
For example, you could use a lambda to call a user-defined function with arguments that don't match the ones expected by the foreach() invocation:
function Foobar(val)
  echo a:val
endfunction

:call foreach([37, 73], {key, val -> Foobar(val)})
37
73

Another example of expression with a side effect is calling add() on a list, for example:
:let result = []
:call foreach([37, 73], {key, val -> add(g:result, val)})
:echo result
[37, 73]


:echo was a bad example to use. I actually want to do something similar to the documentation example - call foreach(mylist, 'let used[v:val] = v:true') - but with a lambda. Based on your comment, I see that :let wouldn't work here either.
By using extend() in the lambda, I was able to get what I wanted with either foreach() or reduce() as the calling function.
However, I was operating under the assumption that reduce() and foreach() would run faster because they're written presumably in C vs. a Vimscript :for loop. Apparently the lambda execution slows things a lot.

Indeed I'd expect using a :for would be quicker if you're doing a :let or similar for each element.

In vim9script, a compiled lambda might be fast enough
